# Transfer execution control from one class to another in Java?

Tags: java, junit4

I have a java main program. This program holds function `main(String[] args)`.
I have another program that holds function of Junit. Both are independent program and under different packages. After running methods from class (having main function), I want to transfer control to Junit class file (i.e. junit class file take control and run program according to @ annotation).

Is this possible?

Note:

- JUnitCore() is not the option. It doesn't for my scenario.
- I do not want to run Junit inside my main program. I want it to run as separate application.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry Karna, that doesn't answer my question. I can run Junit test from my java application. I wanted to transfer control from Main function thread to Junit.

Comment: @Asvhini, can you eloborate on what you mean by "transfer control"?

Comment: It does. Invoking `JunitCore.run()` will invoke junit tests

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich : I mean to say that I do not want my program to come back to main class. Just treat everything (after completion of main class) as a Junit class.

Comment: What should happen after tests are over?

Comment: Display result as Junit does. I mean reporting etc.

Comment: Having a call to JUnitCore.run as the last statement of your main function will have the same effect, no?

Comment: I do not think so. Let me try this with some workaround.

Comment: "*I do not want to run Junit inside my main program. I want it to run as separate application.*" What if you just make a shell script / batch file that first runs your main program, waits for it to finish, and then runs the test program?

Comment: @JasonC - Seems good option to me or May be excellent idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can..

Create the object of `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` and invoke the `run` method with argument as your class containing junit test cases.
Invoke the run method when you want to transfer the control.